# 組み込み機器OSSのライセンス表記

Tags: ライセンス, oss

既存の産業機器（GUI、CUIなど画面インターフェイスなし）にRaspberryPi（Raspbian＋自作アプリ）で機能追加を行いたいです。

自作アプリ部分はMITライセンス、BSDライセンス、Apatchライセンスなどソース開示を義務付けられていないライセンスのOSSライブラリを使用しています。

OSSのライセンス違反にならないように、ライセンス表記をどのように行うか調べておりますが
周りに知見者がおらず、困っています。

1. 画面インターフェイスなしの場合、ライセンスはどこに表記するのが一般的でしょうか？
2. Raspbianには一切改変していませんが、Raspbinanに含まれるOSSライブラリもすべて洗い出しライセンス表示させなければならないという認識ですが、その認識であっているでしょうか？
3. Raspbianにはソース開示が義務付けられたGPL、LGPLを含んでいると思いますが、自社でRaspbianのソース公開しなければならないとの認識ですが、その認識であってますか？
4. 自作アプリはソース開示を義務付けられたライセンスを含んでいませんが、GPL、LGPLを含むRaspbian上で動作しています。Raspbian部分と自作アプリ部分はバイナリが別なので、ソース開示が不要との認識ですが、その認識であっているでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

１．ドキュメントなどに記載しておけばいいです
２．その認識でいいかと思います。まあ、漏れなく全て、というのは難しいかもしれませんが。そこらへんは問い合わせされたときに追記するとか説明すればいいかと。
３．問い合わせを受けたときに開示する、あるいはそのソースの所在を提示する、程度でいいんじゃないでしょうか
４．その認識でいいかと思います